# Regex for replace all new line and tab in sublime text

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

I have multiple strings containing sql queries that outputs with \n and \t symbols in my logs.

Here is one for example

```
SELECT id, codcom, action, dc, tc FROM\n\t\t\t\t(SELECT\n\t\t\t\t\tid, codcom, action, dc, tc\n\t\t\t\tFROM\n\t\t\t\t\tattendance.inout\n\t\t\t\tWHERE\n\t\t\t\t\tdc between '2021-10-25' and '2021-10-31' and cod_ditta = 1 and codcom = 6293\n\t\t\t\tUNION\n\t\t\t\tSELECT\n\t\t\t\t\tid, codcom, action, dc, tc\n\t\t\t\tFROM\n\t\t\t\t\tattendance.inout_timb_ext\n\t\t\t\tWHERE\n\t\t\t\t\tdc between '2021-10-25' and '2021-10-31' and cod_ditta = 1 and codcom = 6293) timbs\n\t\t\t\tORDER BY dc , tc
```

is it possible to use a single regex to replace all the symbols that starts with the backslash symbol with a new line, tab, etcetera?

I know I could achieve the same result with multiple replaces. This question is more out of curiosity.

**What I tried so far**

So far I was able to select all the symbols that I want to replace with the regex (in the `find` section)

```
\\(\w)
```

But when it comes to replace I don't know how to replace it with the actual new line, tab, etc.

I tried this so far (in the `replace` section), without achieving the desired result:

```
\\$1
\\1
```

Comment: You can match all of them and unescape in one code function. There is no built into regex unescape function. You will have to run as many individual replacements as you need for each sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with `\1` because the group will capture the `\\t` which is treated literally and is not `\t` (`tab`).

In sublime text, do it in two steps, use below expressions:

Step 1:

- Find All (regex mode): `(\\t)`
- Replace All:   (space)

Step 2:

- Find All (regex mode): `(\\t)`
- Replace All: `\n` (newline)